# How do I loop 'WebDriverWait' function when it cannot find an information?

Tags: python, selenium, webdriverwait

How do I repeat(loop) the below code even not available 'URL' case?

For example, I do have excel with many URLs of music on Discogs.com.

https://www.discogs.com/master/561393-The-High-School-Musical-Cast-High-School-Musical-2-Soundtrack

https://www.discogs.com/master/1338438-Zedd-Maren-Morris-Grey-The-Middle

https://www.discogs.com/master/606957-Zendaya-Zendaya

...

However, some row does not have the exact information that I wished for. (genres..)
Currently, the code shows "NoSuchWindowException... errors..'
How do I just ignore the not-available URL and repeat the next loop?

```js
driver.get(url)
  genre = None
  try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button#onetrust-accept-btn-handler"))).click()
    genre = [genre.text for genre in WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//tr/th[@scope='row' and contains(., 'Genre')]//following::td[1]//a")))]
  except selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException:

 if genre != None:
    song_url_dict_excel.iloc[i,2] = genre
```

Comment: _NoSuchWindowException_ at which line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get rid of None type error, you can apply `if else None` statement.
Try this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

url = 'https://www.discogs.com/master/561393-The-High-School-Musical-Cast-High-School-Musical-2-Soundtrack'



driver.get(url)
driver.maximize_window()
wait =  WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

button = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button#onetrust-accept-btn-handler'))).click()
genre = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '(//*[@class="table_1fWaB"]/tbody/tr)[1]/td//a')))
for gen in genre:
    gen = gen.text if gen else None
    print(gen)
```

**Output:**

```
Electronic
Rock
Pop
Stage & Screen
```